# How to get stable menu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to place a stable menu in my site. In the site, even if we move down the page, I would like to always display the menu on  the top.

Example: [iplex.co.in](http://iplex.co.in/index.php)... Please visit this site for demo.

Comment: Use `position: fixed; top:0` for top menu css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `position:fixed` you can set the position of the element relative to the browser window.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#main
{
height:1200px;
width:auto;
border:1px solid Red;   
}

#menu
{
height:50px;
width:auto;
background-color:#DDD;
position:fixed;
top:20px;
left:60px;
}



#menu ul li
{
display:inline;
float:left;
margin:5px 10px;

}
```

​

**[See working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4DK3R/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by placing the `<div>` with `positions : fixed` for sample

```
#navigationMenu {
position: fixed;
margin-left: 1086px;
z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `position: fixed` in order to make some element fixed in the page.

HTML:

```
<ul id=menu>
<li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>
<li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>
<li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

For your specific usage, check this page: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html

Answer (score 0):

use a `position:fixed;` property to your  menu `id`.